# Getting the name of a checkbox submitted by GET

Tags: python, html, get

So I'm trying to use the CGI module that comes with Python, on a Python Server Page.

I want to know if there is any way to pull the name of the checkbox, when it is submitted. I don't actually need to know the status of whether it is on or off (because off won't submit to the new page), just what the name is, because that's how the script is going to run.

I.e., on my first page I have

```
<input type="checkbox" name="AV-D01">
```

I submit this form, and it has the form of

```
formchangedate.psp?AV-D01=on
```

All I care to pull from this is the AV-D01 - is there anyway to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cgi.FieldStorage()` returns a dictionary containing the parameters of the request.

Comment: Hrm, I assigned cgi.FieldStorage() to test, and outputted that, and got: FieldStorage(None, None, [])

Comment: Then no parameters are being sent with the request.